# Is there a way to remove the hover effect on just light boxes on Squarespace?

Tags: css, squarespace

I need to keep the hover effect for this gallery grid, but I would like to remove it when the images in the grid are clicked on (i.e., within the Lightbox), is there an option for this?

Here is the webpage: https://www.kroschlab.com/people-test

Note how the hover effect occurs when you are in grid view (I want), but it also occurs when you click on the images and are in the Lightbox (I don't want).

In summary: is there a way to show text in the Lightbox without requiring a hover-over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by overlaying a background that was identical to the hover background, and displaying the text using opacity.

```
    .yui3-lightbox2 .sqs-lightbox-meta {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0, 0, 0.7);
}
```